# Stopping a thread after all other threads I've created in the same process die

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, process

I'm trying to write a library that any process can use for logging. I want to have a dedicated worker thread in my class that writes log messages through some mechanism (pipes, TCP sockets, whatever) to another process on a remote machine, so that the code looks like this for the logging constructor (the reason for doing it this way is so that you don't block the thread that's logging from stopping its execution in the event that the logging server is down on the remote machine):

```
public LogWriter()
{
    queueWriter = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (messageQueued.WaitOne())
        {
            Message message;
            while (messageQueue.TryDequeue(out message))
            {
                bool successful = false;
                while (!successful)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _logger.PostMessage(message);
                        successful = true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _logger = new Logger();
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    queueWriter.Start();
}
```

So if you had an application, you could just log like this:

```
LogWriter logWriter = new LogWriter();
logWriter.Debug("This is an example of how you'd send a debug log to the writer. This message would get translated into a Message object, queued up, and the dedicated writer would be signaled to start writing queued messages.");
```

`messageQueue` is a `ConcurrentQueue<Message>`.I want `queueWriter` to always stop ten seconds **after all other threads that I've explicitly created in the process hosting it except for itself die** in order to give it some time to finish writing the logs it has in its `messageQueue`, but not to block the process from closing (so after ten seconds, if it hasn't finished writing all its logs, we don't care anymore, just stop the thread).

Notes:

- Making `queueWriter` a background thread isn't good enough. I don't want to kill `queueWriter` when the parent thread dies, because it may not have had enough time to finish writing its pending logs.
- Subscribing to `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Exited` is not good enough, either. The `queueWriter` thread keeps the process up.
- I'd like for it to be usable as a library, and I don't want developers to have to manually signal the worker to stop after ten seconds on shutdown of their application or process. I just want to be able to track when all the threads except for the worker thread are dead, wait ten seconds, and then shut down the worker thread.
- Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count may be handy, but doing some tests with it, it gives you all the threads your application uses (like unmanaged threads, library threads, and even threads that you haven't explicitly created yourself, in the sense that you haven't written code to start that thread explicitly).

So how can this be done? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with threads. You can with a separate process though.

Comment: Most likely not possible. You don't really have a way to know what each thread in the process does, so even if you enumerate each and every one there's always the chance the host process has made arrangements you can't possibly determine.

Comment: @Jon Not each thread in the process, just each thread that the library itself created, if I read the question right.

Comment: @zespri: It says "but not block the process from closing" -- I read that as "I want to know when the process is exiting so that I can put a countdown on my threads".

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That is a good suggestion, but my concern is that you'd have to send data to that process from this one. Can you always ensure delivery between two processes on the same machine (will my communication channel always be up)? What if my process dies at some point? I would still need to give it time to send all the data it needs to send to the other process. You see how this ends up where we started? I would need to buffer and then send that data. I could block to try and ensure delivery and send that data, but that could slow execution time by a lot.

Comment: ...and also that other process would always have to be up and running ahead of time. What if it isn't up at that time? Do you start it up? What if someone stops it? My communication channel goes down. If I make blocking calls to log, it no longer works, no code execution works anymore, going back to the need for buffering like I have up in the question. Also, it will no longer be a library solution that developers could use.

Comment: Presumably you add the queue because the network can be slow and unreliable. But communicating with a process on the same machine is fast, fast enough to communicate synchronously. And you can monitor the process, and launch a new one if it were to die.

Comment: Communicating with a different process may not be the ideal solution, but it certainly looks like the only option you have. Threads won't do it.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I think you are correct. The more I think about it, the more it makes sense to have a second, local process that handles this. The library could kick that process off if it hasn't been started yet, even subscribe to it so that it has a list of processes that have invoked it, and so it can actually shut itself down when its done writing all of its logs after all of the original, invoking process die. Yes, I think that's it. Unless someone has a better solution for getting the count of threads you've explicitly created, that might be the only way, even with its caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with threads. You can do it with a separate process though.

Presumably you add the queue because the network can be slow and unreliable. But communicating with a process on the same machine is fast, fast enough to communicate synchronously. And you can monitor the process, and launch a new one if it were to die.

Comment: The only other option is to just acknowledge that logging happens on a best effort basis. Even a persistent, transactional queue cannot guarantee message delivery, if you have a power cut before the transaction commits. And if it is best effort thing, a background thread might be acceptable. It certainly would be easier.